# I cannot get makefile to work

Tags: makefile

I have been fighting with makefile and I need help. I am running a virtual linux window in windows.

from a folder containing my main.c file, I type make and I get

```
$make
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -g -Wall -I c:\intelFPGA\16.1\embedded\ip\altera\hps\altera_hps\hwlib\include _c main.c -o main.o
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -g -Wall -I c:\intelFPGA\16.1\embedded\ip\altera\hps\altera_hps\hwlib\include  _c main.c -o main.o, ...)failed.
make(e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [main.o] Error 2
```

This folder contains the following files and an empty folder.
main.c
Makefile
my_first_hps

If I type "where make", I get.

```
$where make
c:\intelFPGA_lite\16.1\nios2eds\bin\gnu\H-x86_64-mingw32\bin\make.exe
c:\intelFPGA\16.1\quartus\bin64\cygwin\bin\make.exe
c:\Coreutils\bin\make.exe
```

My Makefile is.

```
#
TARGET = my_first_hps

#
CROSS_COMPILE = arm-linux-gnueabihf-
CFLAGS = -g -Wall  -I ${SOCEDS_DEST_ROOT}c:/intelFPGA/embedded/ip/altera/hps/altera_hps/hwlib/include
LDFLAGS =  -g -Wall 
CC = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
ARCH= arm

build: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): main.o 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS)   $^ -o $@ 

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET) *.a *.o *~
```

Comment: Looks to me like it's gcc it can't find, not make.

Comment: There are header files in the "c:\intelFPGA\.....\include" that are needed. There is a gcc.exe here  "\intelFPGA_lite\16.1\quartus\bin64\cygwin\bin\gcc.exe. " What would you suggest?

Comment: Seeing if you can run gcc from the command line, using the very same command that make would be using (`arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`). Does it work from there (produce output from gcc), or do you get the same error?

Comment: My main.c is the simple "Hello World". I ran gcc main.c -o hello and then I tried ./hello and I got, "Hello World" on the black screen.

Comment: Ok. Look at the command line in your $make command. What is `_c` right after the include (right before `main.c`)? Looks like a typo that should be `-c` instead of `_c`.

Comment: That is a typo from what I copied from the black screen. It does read -c main.

Comment: I was not able to copy/paste from the black screen.

Comment: If you can't provide *accurate details*, how do you expect to get help? You should learn to copy/paste from your terminal window, or how to pipe the output to a text file that you can then open to copy/paste from instead.

Comment: When you run `gcc main.c -o hello`, you get a working program. What happens when you run `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc main.c -o hello`?

Comment: I get/...... bash: arm-linux: command not found

Comment: Try `whereis arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc`

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but for those who get the same error, I just changed the following line:

```
CC = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc
```

to

```
CC = $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc.exe
```

which has worked for me. Also don't forget that you should have Altera EDS and DS-5 installed. I installed DS-5 at the same place with EDS:

[image: ds-5 installation location image]